# Android -- Is SQLite deprecated or something? (Non-SDK warning spam)

Tags: android, sqlite

so I made a basic application using the Room ORM to take care of my persistence (which uses SQLite). I'm a huge fan of SQLite myself, and am very familiar with it, such is why I chose room.

But every time I run my app, I get close to 1000 lines of warnings of "Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->.... " (the .... part is slightly different with every warning message).

From my understanding, that means I'm accessing non-sdk interfaces that may be removed in future versions without notice.

In which case, does that mean that SQLLite is deprecated in Android? I couldn't find any source online saying such a thing. But I really can't understand why else I'd be getting so many of these warnings.

Or is it just that Room is outdated? I tried with both android 11 and 10 and had the same problem.

I saw one other solution here which was to try and close the "Database Inspector" bundled with Android studio. Problem is: I'd like to use it, and every time I close it/remove from sidebar, it opens itself back up on the next run of my app.

Just wondering what the situation is here. Hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In which case, does that mean that SQLLite is deprecated in Android?

No.

> Or is it just that Room is outdated?

No.

> every time I run my app, I get close to 1000 lines of warnings of "Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->.... " (the .... part is slightly different with every warning message).

> From my understanding, that means I'm accessing non-sdk interfaces that may be removed in future versions without notice.

Something — Room or Database Inspector, most likely, given your description — is using greylisted APIs. Room is created by Google. Database Inspector *probably* is created by Google (if not, it would be JetBrains). The decision of what hidden APIs get on the greylist is made by Google.

So, at some point, Google will need to talk to Google and decide what to do about Google's decision that affects Google's code. It is extraordinarily unlikely that some future version of Android will be released that somehow breaks Room and/or Database Inspector.

So, your focus for those warnings is whether you *directly* are using those hidden APIs. If you are not, then I would not spend much time worrying about it.

Comment: Off-topic: Thank you so much [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware). This answer made my day. It drew a big smile on my face :D .